# How can I load code to a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

Let's say I have a microcontroller, for example, Atmel's ATmega328. Then, I look at ATmega328 datasheet, find its Instruction Set Architecture and, based on it, create an assembly code. Now I get the code and, manually, transform it to binary code.

Now I want to load my runnable ATmega328's binary code into the microcontroller itself. But I want to do it without using Atmel IDE or anything like that. I want to do it sending digital signals to the microcontroller pins.

Is that possible? Is there a protocol to do it? Where can I find this kind of information for each microcontroller?

Thank you! (Outside resources are also welcome)

Comment: Did you try looking further in the datasheet?

Comment: The relevant keyword/search term you are looking for is "bootloader", assuming you want to use an on-board communication peripheral (as opposed to an external programmer/debugger)

Comment: Seems are essentially asking how to build your own circuit programmer/in-circuit debugger. Please note that unless you are really interested in building one, it is a huge waste of time, and you aren't likely to come up with something better or cheaper than the existing commercial tools already available.

Comment: @felipeek Its better to ask *specific* questions in your post than ask open ended questions. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the ATmega328 flash memory, and fuses, are programmable on a brand new, unprogrammed chip (no bootloader) over its SPI interface. So you need to control four of the ATmega328 pins; the SPI interface and RESET.

Read section "31.8. Serial Downloading" in the full ATmega328 datasheet (not the summary datasheet), which begins:

> Both the Flash and EEPROM memory arrays can be programmed using the
>   serial SPI bus while RESET is pulled to GND. The serial interface
>   consists of pins SCK, MOSI (input) and MISO (output).

One way to make your own In-System-Programmer (ISP) is to use an Arduino. There are examples of how to control the SPI interface of the target ATmega328 on the web, but you could start by reading the code in [Using an Arduino as an AVR ISP (In-System Programmer)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP). It is a 'full' ISP programmer, which works with avrdude, which is an Open Source programming application. You will need to figure out how to build a binary whoch avrdude can read. Potentially the easiest way to start is to use the GNU gcc binutils assembler and linker. They will produce a binary whch avrdude can upload with no other 'moving parts' (applications).

If you want something even more minimal, you'll have quite a lot of work to do. However, a useful step might be understand how the SPI upload works. You might do that by extracting the upload code of that Arduino AVR-ISP program, throw the rest of the program away. Let's call this the 'upload program'. Then, instead of implementing a protocol to upload the binary program from avrdude, store the binary code that you have created representing your program, in that new upload program as data. Modify the program to upload that data using the upload code. This gives you a self contained upload system, which does need the avr-gcc tool chain without using the Atmel IDE. When you load the combined upload and binary-program data onto an Arduino, it will upload to a ATmega328.

You can then figure out how you want to proceed from their, knowing you have a working upload system. For example you could then invent your won protocol to talk to your own uploader, and your own format for the binary code.

Edit:
A bootloader is loaded onto an unprogrammed ATmega this way. However, you don't need a bootloader if you have something which will program the ATmegas flash and fuses over SPI.

There are several Open Source ATmega bootloaders, so you could use own of those, or use one as the basis of your won.

I would suggest you look at [avrdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/), which might be a adequate fit for uploading code. I have not read its source, but a close friend has, and said it is very complex because it works with almost all Atmel chips ever made. He wrote a simple SPI loader, which only worked for a single ATmega, from scratch in a few days.

I strongly recommend looking at GNU binutils for AVR. You get all of these when you download and install the Arduino IDE. They include an assembler, which will be much more productive than hand assembling AVR instructions, and a linker which will produce 'proper' binary files that programs like avrdude can upload. The binutils also have handy tools like a disassembler (for properly formatted binary code files).

Edit 2:
@AndrewP has pointed out that a system like a Raspberry-Pi can be connected electronically to an Atmega (either with a bit of level shifting, or by running the ATega at 3.3V) so that it can drive the SPI interface directly. Or, if you have an old enough PC you might also use the parallel port.

(Personally, I'd suggest looking at FTDI USB to SPI cables, or their general purpose USB interface hardware which would allow you to program the SPI interface from a host PC over USB)

(Also, IIRC avrdude runs on the R-Pi. I haven't checked, but there is likely a version of the GNU binutils for the R-Pi already compiled and ready to install.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Are bootloaders loaded into the microcontroller using the SPI interface?

Comment: @felipeek - I have updated my answer, but the summary is, yes bootloaders are uploaded onto the ATmega using SPI.

Comment: +1 for avrdude. If you have a raspberry pi (or, I believe, a parallel port on your computer), you can wire directly to the ATMega and load programs directly without a bootloader https://learn.adafruit.com/program-an-avr-or-arduino-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins/overview

Comment: @AndrewP - very good point. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I load code to a microcontroller?

It's as easy as programming the microcontroller rom and instructions for this are in the microcontroller's datasheet.

> Let's say I have a microcontroller, for example, Atmel's ATmega328. Then, I look at ATmega328 datasheet, find its Instruction Set Architecture and, based on it, create an assembly code. Now I get the code and, manually, transform it to binary code. Now I want to load my runnable ATmega328's binary code into the microcontroller itself. But I want to do it without using Atmel IDE or anything like that. I want to do it sending digital signals to the microcontroller pins.

You partly answered your question. Programming any microcontroller does involve sending a special sequence of digital signals to certain pins depending on the functionality you want the microcontroller to produce in the end.

> Is that possible?

Of course

> Is there a protocol to do it?

The datasheet for the microcontroller will instruct you on what series of signals you need to send to it to erase the contents in rom, and it will instruct you on how to program a new byte etc. Generally, its a good idea to erase the existing rom contents first before programming the microcontroller with new code so that you won't get unexpected results.

Now this is where things get crazy. Many new computers (particularly laptops) do NOT come with a port that's easy to interface a custom microcontroller circuit to (unless you buy a premade microcontroller programmer and run the associated software with it). In other words, you have USB in todays computers.

Back in the day, you had computers with parallel ports that you could set up as a standard port and you could actually connect LED's to them (with a resistor in series) and write a line or two of code that lights up the LED's of your choice.

I made a programmer for the AT89C2051 microcontroller that interfaces with the parallel port, and even though I have to wait a few minutes to program 1000 bytes of code on to it, the damn thing still works.

This is the link to a programmer for that particular microcontroller online:

http://www.oocities.org/dinceraydin/8051/index.html

I know I'm too carried away on the 8051 series of microcontrollers but it gives you an idea of how to throw code onto a microcontroller.

> Where can I find this kind of information for each microcontroller?

In the microcontroller's datasheet. Just enter the part number in google, and you should come across a PDF that you can download which explains the microcontroller.

Comment: Nice explanation. Just one question: if the microcontroller has a bootloader, erasing the ROM to send the code manually would also erase the bootloader, right? Actually, since the program will be loaded in the beginning of the memory, even if the ROM is not erased, the bootloader (or jumper to bootloader) would be overwritten... is it correct or I am missing something?

Comment: It's probably as hard to find a computer with a parallel port, as it is to find 8051 chips on the spot market. All of that stuff is very much outdated - modern MCUs use JTAG/SWD, which is a serial interface.

Comment: @felipeek Yes, because the bootloader AFAIK is software-based. Once you do an erase operation (which takes a bit longer than a write-a-byte operation) then every piece of software stored on the chip is erased. In the old days, if one section of the rom is written to, that section of the rom can't be rewritten to again until the entire unit is erased. As for parallel port, there might be usb-to-parallel port converters available on ebay that may be able to do the job, but I never tested one because I have a parallel port.